# Shared preferences - _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm following the tutorial about shared preferences and I'm stuck with `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`. I've already found a few solutions but they are not perfect for my case or I just simply can't implement them properly :(
On the screen, you can see where this error appears:
[image: _CastError]

My files below:

main.dart

```html
import 'package:day08_user_settings/preferences_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'models.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _preferencesService = PreferencesService();
  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();

  var _selectedGender = Gender.FEMALE;
  final _selectedLanguages = Set<ProgrammingLanguage>();
  var _isEmployed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('User settings'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: TextField(
              controller: _usernameController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
            ),
          ),
          RadioListTile(
              title: const Text('Female'),
              value: Gender.FEMALE,
              groupValue: _selectedGender,
              onChanged: (newValue) =>
                  setState(() => _selectedGender = newValue!)),
          RadioListTile(
              title: const Text('Male'),
              value: Gender.MALE,
              groupValue: _selectedGender,
              onChanged: (newValue) =>
                  setState(() => _selectedGender = newValue!)),
          RadioListTile(
              title: const Text('Other'),
              value: Gender.OTHER,
              groupValue: _selectedGender,
              onChanged: (newValue) =>
                  setState(() => _selectedGender = newValue!)),
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text('Dart'),
            value: _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.DART),
            onChanged: (_) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.DART)
                    ? _selectedLanguages.remove(ProgrammingLanguage.DART)
                    : _selectedLanguages.add(ProgrammingLanguage.DART);
              });
            },
          ),
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text('JavaScript'),
            value: _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.JAVASCRIPT),
            onChanged: (_) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.JAVASCRIPT)
                    ? _selectedLanguages.remove(ProgrammingLanguage.JAVASCRIPT)
                    : _selectedLanguages.add(ProgrammingLanguage.JAVASCRIPT);
              });
            },
          ),
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text('Kotlin'),
            value: _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.KOTLIN),
            onChanged: (_) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.KOTLIN)
                    ? _selectedLanguages.remove(ProgrammingLanguage.KOTLIN)
                    : _selectedLanguages.add(ProgrammingLanguage.KOTLIN);
              });
            },
          ),
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text('Swift'),
            value: _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.SWIFT),
            onChanged: (_) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.SWIFT)
                    ? _selectedLanguages.remove(ProgrammingLanguage.SWIFT)
                    : _selectedLanguages.add(ProgrammingLanguage.SWIFT);
              });
            },
          ),
          SwitchListTile(
            title: const Text('Is Employed'),
            value: _isEmployed,
            onChanged: (newValue) => setState(
              () => _isEmployed = newValue,
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: _saveSettings,
            child: const Text('Save Settings'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _saveSettings() {
    final newSettings = Settings(
      username: _usernameController.text,
      gender: _selectedGender,
      programmingLanguages: _selectedLanguages,
      isEmployed: _isEmployed,
    );
    print(newSettings);
    _preferencesService.saveSettings(newSettings);
  }
}
```

models.dart

```html
enum Gender { FEMALE, MALE, OTHER }

enum ProgrammingLanguage { DART, JAVASCRIPT, KOTLIN, SWIFT }

class Settings {
  String? username;
  Gender? gender;
  Set<ProgrammingLanguage>? programmingLanguages;
  bool? isEmployed;

  Settings({
    required String username,
    required Gender gender,
    required Set<ProgrammingLanguage> programmingLanguages,
    required bool isEmployed,
  });
}
```

preferences-service.dart

```html
import 'package:day08_user_settings/models.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class PreferencesService {
  Future saveSettings(Settings settings) async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await preferences.setString('username', settings.username ?? '');
    await preferences.setBool('isEmployed', settings.isEmployed ?? false);
    await preferences.setInt('Gender', settings.gender?.index ?? 0);
    await preferences.setStringList(
      'ProgrammingLanguages',
      settings.programmingLanguages!
          .map((lang) => lang.index.toString())
          .toList(),
    );

    print('Save Settings');
  }
}
```

Please help with this because I don't have any idea at this point and I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the error `setting.programmingLanguages` is null. What do you want to do if the list is empty?

1. If you want to remove whatever is in preferences from before use `remove('ProgrammingLanguages')`.
2. You can just skip `setString()` if `setting.programmingLanguages==null`

P.S. I advice you to have keys as constant values at the top of the file, so you don't have to copy paste and less chance for a typo. Like `const programLang = 'ProgrammingLanguages'`

Comment: What do you want to do if the list is empty? ->  if I'm correct regarding the tutorial when you check the box of one of the languages then `setting.programmingLanguages` mapping by index and converting it to list. I put "!" because "?" didn't worked as VSC gives those options.

Comment: if you use ? it means that the whole statement will return null if `setting.programmingLanguages` is null, instead of trowing an error, but the function `setString()` can't take null as a second argument. So the smart thing would be to check if it is null and only then call `setString()`
Like this:
`if(setting.programmingLanguages != null) {await preferences.setStringList('ProgrammingLanguages',settings.programmingLanguages! .map((lang)=>lang.index.toString()).toList(),);
}
`

Comment: That worked well. I didn't put `settings` before `programmingLanguage`. Now it's ok. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)` error is triggered because you tried to use a null-valued variable. When you enter **"!"** in `settings.programmingLanguages!.map((lang) => lang.index.toString()).toList(),` , in theory you are **ensuring** that the value of `programmingLanguages` is not null. I suggest you do a check first to verify that the value is not null, and only then use the **"!"** in your variable.

Comment: You mean to check if `programmingLanguages  != null` in preferences_service.dart?

Comment: Yup. Do this check before saving it to `setStringList`

Comment: I've done something like this:
`if (programmingLanguages != null) {
      await preferences.setStringList(
          'ProgrammingLanguages',
          settings.programmingLanguages
              .map((lang) => lang.index.toString())
              .toList());
    } `
but still got `The method 'map' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`
So when I add "!" everything is fine then. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Yup. Adding the "!" should work.

Comment: There need to be `settings` before `programmingLanguange` which I didn't put in. 
As @noxgood mentioned in his comment there need to be `settings` before. 
Appreciate your help :)